# Include a pdf page by page with descriptions after each page

Tags: labels, pdfpages, include

I want to do the following:
I want to generate a script from my lecture slides. My lecture slides are in pdf (generated via latex-beamer), but in beamer-size. Now I want to make a script from that, in a4-size. In that script, there is supposed to one slide of the lectureslides per script-page, but additionally a text with a closer description of each slide. 
To have as little work as possible in doing that, it would be perfect if I just had to write something like

```
\begin{page}[17] 
  %description of slide #17 from the lecture-slides
\end{page}[17]
```

And further, if I do not have any description for one page of the lecture-slides, it should still stand on a page.

How do I do something like that? I am really not good enough in latex to write a script like that, however I think it must be easily possible. Does anybody have a hint for me?

Comment: You could beamer let do the work for you and insert the additional information as a `\note{}` and sequentially output the slides as the normal slide on top of the page and the note page below.

Answer (score 2):

The beamer way of doing this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

% notepage for every slide, even if empty
\makeatletter 
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{%   
    \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%   
    \gdef\beamer@notes{{}}%  
}
\makeatother

% empty and uncounted note pages
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \vskip3\baselineskip% a little space 
    \insertnote
}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        slide with note
        \note{additional information blow the slide

            can be long and include linebreaks test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
        }
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        test without note
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to compile the beamer version of the slides, comment out

```
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
```

It's also possible to set up latex automation tools or your editor to automatically compile both versions.

---

In comparison to the external document which inserts the beamer slides as images, this approach has the advantage that you can interact with the content of the slides, e.g. when `\ref{}`ering to sections, images or equations. So

[image: Keep calm and let beamer do it for you]

Answer (score 1):

As samcarter commented, `beamer` already offers this possibility with `notes` environment. But if you prefer to use an external document for your notes, you could use something like:

```
\newenvironment{mypage}[2]{%
    \includegraphics[page=#2, width=\linewidth]{#1}\\[1ex]}{\newpage}
```

`mypage` environment uses two parameters, the first one is the presentation file to be commented, and the second the number of the slide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{mypage}[2]{%
    \includegraphics[page=#2, width=\linewidth]{#1}\\[1ex]}{\newpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{mypage}{beamer}{1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mypage}

\begin{mypage}{beamer}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mypage}

\begin{mypage}{beamer}{3}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mypage}

\begin{mypage}{beamer}{4}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mypage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As I suppose that each document refers to one presentation, this can be declared as a default parameter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{mypage}[2][beamer]{%
    \includegraphics[page=#2, width=\linewidth]{#1}\\[1ex]}{\newpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{mypage}{1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mypage}

\begin{mypage}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mypage}

\begin{mypage}{3}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mypage}

\begin{mypage}{4}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mypage}
\end{document}
```

And although I think that samcarter solution is the way to go, a `tcolorbox` version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{mypage}[2][beamer]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=blue, colback=white, colbacktitle=blue!50!white, fonttitle=\bfseries, title={Comments to slide #2}, bicolor, colbacklower=blue!20, drop fuzzy shadow]
\includegraphics[page=#2, width=\linewidth]{#1}
\tcblower}{\end{tcolorbox}\newpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{mypage}{2}
\lipsum[3]
\end{mypage}

\begin{mypage}{3}
\lipsum[5]
\end{mypage}
\end{document}
```

[image]